# E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)?

Tags: permissions, resources

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

this is what I get if I try to run sudo apt install on basically any command.

Comment: That happens when something else is using it in the background, like updates.

Comment: Is there a command that can show me all the "else" running ?

Comment: Even better there's the GUI System Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Following errors seems to occur due to multitudes of reasons, for example, multiple dpkg instances or running out of space or because you forgot sudo for apt-get.

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

To diagnose this, first add this in your bash script at start:

```
set -o xtrace
```

This would show each command with + sign prefix as they get executed. In my case this was indeed happening because I forgot to add sudo in front of apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, I got this error because Ubuntu was running an update automatically. Here's what I did to verify it

```
# apt-get update firefox
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

# lsof | grep lock-frontend
unattended  1601  root  11uW   REG   8,1    0   1207581  /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
{{...more lines like this...}}

# ps all
{{...many lines but some mention dpkg, for example:}}
{{...}}  do_wait  Ss+  pts/1    0:00  /usr/bin/dpkg --status-{{...}}
{{...}}  do_wait  S+   pts/1    0:00  /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/i{{...}}

 # top
 {{ shows dpkg-related processes so you can see that they're doing something }}
```

Once `top` stopped showing dpkg-related processes---in my case only 5 minutes later---I was able to use `apt-get` normally.